# Listen an audio file in a Skype conversation

Tags: audio, skype

In a Skype conversation I'd like that the other person could hear an audio file (with enough quality to be understood).

I have a Real Player file (.ram) and I want to play it, pause it , forward it and I want that the other person in the conversation can hear what I'm also hearing (it's for teaching purposes). While I'm playing the audio file is not neccessary that the other person can hear my voice through the microphone (though it would be great too).

I've tried to set in the Audio Settings the microphone as "RealTek Digital Input" instead of the microphone, but trying against the Test Service without success.

How can I do that (without a pay-per-use software)? How can I change the microphone to be set as the audio from my speakers?

Comment: Which operating system are you using ?

Comment: @Karolos Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to follow [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20595-what-u-hear-recording-enable.html) article and enable "Stereo Mix" and set it as Microphone in Skype Audio settings. [image: Skype Audio settings]
<sub>(source: [skype.com](https://support.skype.com/library/SKYPE/screenshots/FA11067p.png))</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much. I had been trying for over a week. This works! :)

Comment: Seem like this solution is work only for devices which have Realtek Audio driver. Isn't it have a common solution for all PC?